# Resource management when using "use" inside a sequence expression

Tags: f#, sequence, resource-management

I have a simple sequence expression that makes use of a resource that I'd like to clean up when I'm finished:

```fsharp
type MyObject() =
    member this.Items =
        seq {
            use resource = ResourcePool.Get()
            let c = resource.ValueCount
            if c > 0 then
                for i in 0 .. c - 1 do
                    yield resource.GetValue i
        }
```

If I then use the sequence to iterate, say, half-way through the items, when will the resource be Disposed?

For example:

```fsharp
// ...

let foo = MyObject
let item = foo.Items |> Seq.find ( fun i -> i.Name = "name" )

// ...
```

Will `resource` be disposed after Seq.find is finished? Or do I need to reconsider my resource management strategy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be disposed when the `IEnumerator` is disposed, regardless of how many items are enumerated. For functions in the `Seq` module this happens when the function exits ([see `tryFind`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L984) as an example). `GetEnumerator` is rarely called directly in user code, but when it is it should be done with `use` instead of `let`.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm afraid of... when is the IEnumerator disposed? Is my resource going to hang around in memory for a long time?

Comment: The short answer is no. I added some more details.